# Renaming xcode project giving issues

Tags: ios, xcode

I renamed my xcode (version 6.3[image]) project and it worked fine, but as I shifted it to another machine, it didn't show any classes/ scheme. Even clicking on a new scheme is showing a "None" Target. See the screen shot.

Comment: Do you have a copy of your project (pre-renaming it) to try on other machine? If the pre-renamed version runs on other machine then this helps confirm that renaming the project has broken something.

Comment: Yes it has definitely broken something..but I don't have the other copy before re-naming. I accidentally deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by choosing the file inspector of .xcodeproj file and corrected the Location. It was picking some other location of any previous version. After that I created a new scheme and it works like a charm now!!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the left of the "My Mac" (where it usually says the name of the scheme), select Edit scheme, and on Run set the Executable to your APP_NAME.app

Comment: It is showing a None Target (at the time of creating new scheme) and currently it is showing My Mac after I created a new scheme, otherwise it was blank. Also, as it has none target, so Edit scheme is doing nothing.